# Fill column with timestamps using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a button to stamp time into a column of cells, each time the button is pressed I would like it to move to the cell below e.g., A1, A2, A3 etc.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click() 
With Range("A1") 
.Value = Now()

.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM" 
End With 
End Sub
```

This adds the current time stamp to A1 and each time replaces the contents, when excel recognises A1 is full I want it to print in the next cell down. Is there some kind of +1 loop i should be using. I have not used VB before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` instead.  It will leave `A1` blank as it's offsetting from the last row by one row, but will add to A2, A3, A4, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the current last used row in `Column A` each time you run the macro. Then you move down one row with `Offset(1)` to drop your new value

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

Dim LR As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    .Range("A" & LR).Value = Format(Now, "h:mm:ss AM/PM")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click() 
With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 
.Value = Now()

.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM" 
End With 
End Sub
```

As commented by Darren